# jquery modal popup read from a file

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, modal-dialog

For the below code,

there ia a form in the location /home/form.php .How can this form be opened with the below code.i.e, the modal dialog

```
     $dialog.html(data)
     .dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        position: ['right','bottom'] ,
        title: 'Emp Form',
        draggable: false,
        width : 300,
        height : 400,
        resizable : false
     });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `load()`:

```
 $('#dialogThing).load("/home/form.php").dialog({ ... }).dialog("open");
```

You'll want to be careful about initializing a dialog more than once; I can't remember whether the normal jQuery UI dialog detects that.  It might of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open existing page, you could use iframe to load the content inside your dialog box.

Assuming $dialog.html sets html content of the dialog box, you can do something like that:

```
$dialog.html('<iframe id="myFrame" src="/home/form.php"></iframe>')
```